# Quickest implementation of Java Map for a small number of entries

Tags: java, performance, collections, dictionary

What is the quickest implementation of [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for a very small number of entries (under 15 elements or so)? Both thread-safe and non-thread-safe.

Comment: Use `ConcurrentHashMap` for thread-safe.

Comment: What are you mapping to what? i.e. is it a `Map<Integer, String>`, a `Map<Double, Long>`, etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all entries can be represented as Enums, use [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):

> This implementation combines the richness and safety of the Map
>   interface with a speed approaching that of an array. If you want to
>   map an enum to a value, you should always use an EnumMap in preference
>   to an array.

If no, [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is good solution. It provides constant time for basic operations, like `get()` and `put()`:

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets.

Just rembember to set low `capacity` value in your HashMap:

> Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or
>   the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.

Of course, above implementations are not thread safe. The best thread-safe implementation in this case will be [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). It combines high performance of HashMap with being thread-safe.

[Here is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html) good comparison of different Map implementations.

Edit: [Here is](http://b010.blogspot.com/2009/05/speed-comparison-of-1-javas-built-in.html) an interesting comparison of different `HashMap` implementations. It seems, that, at least for primitive types, there are faster alternatives than built-in `HashMap`.

Edit2: Due to Peter Lawrey's answer I decided to perform some test, comparing `ConcurrentHashMap` and `Collections.synchronizedMap()` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("\n===== ConcurrentHashMap =====");
      testMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
      System.out.println("\n===== Collections.synchronizedMap()  =====");
      testMap(Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>()));
}

    static final int N = 5;
    static final int R = 1000000;

    public static void testMap(Map map) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("\n-- " + N*R + " puts(key, value) --");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
                map.put(i, new float[] { 0f, 1f, 2f, 3f, 4f });
            map.clear();
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000.0);

        System.out.println("\n-- " + N*R + " get(key) --");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
                map.get(i); 
            map.clear();
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000.0);
    }

}
```

My results are:

===== ConcurrentHashMap =====

- 5000000 puts(key, value) - 0.99714195 s
- 5000000 get(key) - 0.452227427 s

===== Collections.synchronizedMap()  =====

- 5000000 puts(key, value) - 0.586431367 s
- 5000000 get(key) - 0.376051088 s

So, Peter is probably right - for small maps, `Collections.synchronizedMap()` is faster.

Comment: +1 The only problem is that ConcurrentHashMap has a high overhead for small Maps.

Comment: 1. "HashMap ... provides constant time..." - for a small number of entries it will probably spend more time computing hashes compared to a simple equality test in a loop. Hence the question. 2. Single threaded testing of thread-safe collections is meaningless. Also see Google Caliper for microbeanchmarks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a compact Map you can use the

Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

if you don't need thread safety, drop the `Collections.synchronizedMap`  And if you want the collection to use as little memory as possible you can do something like this.

Map map = new HashMap<>(4, 1.0f);

This will store 4 key/values (or more) using a minimum of memory.  It will be about half the size of an empty standard HashMap.

The problem with using ConcurrentHashMap is that it is heavy weight for a small collection i.e. it uses many objects and about 1 KB of memory if empty.

To get accurate memory usage, you need to use `-XX-UseTLAB` on the command line

```
public static void main(String sdf[]) throws Exception {
    testCreateSize("ConcurrentHashMap", ConcurrentHashMap::new);
    testCreateSize("HashMap", HashMap::new);
    testCreateSize("synchronized HashMap", () -> {
        return Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
    });
    testCreateSize("small synchronized HashMap", () -> {
        return Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>(4, 2.f));
    });

}

public static void testCreateSize(String description, Supplier<Map<Integer, Integer>> supplier) {
    // warmup.
    supplier.get();
    long start = memoryUsed();
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = supplier.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        map.put(i, i);
    }
    long used = memoryUsed() - start;
    System.out.printf("Memory used for %s, was %,d bytes%n", description, used);

}

public static long memoryUsed() {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
}
```

prints

```
Memory used for ConcurrentHashMap, was 272 bytes
Memory used for HashMap, was 256 bytes
Memory used for synchronized HashMap, was 288 bytes
Memory used for small synchronized HashMap, was 240 bytes
```

You can save 32 more bytes by using synchronized methods in the class which uses the map.

Comment: But ConcurrentHashMap is much more efficent than Collections.synchronizedMap(...).

Comment: @Kao for large collections, yes, for lots of small collections CHM is pretty bad.

Comment: @Kao Not "pretty bad" but less efficient.

Comment: That's not a fair experiment. You didn't use the int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, or concurrencyLevel for the ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @joseph true. You can do the same for HashMap.

Comment: @PeterLawrey awesome advice! will definitely try and use minimal Map size and 1.0f as the load factor.

Answer (score 1):

[I'd say HashMaps.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

`HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap <String, Object> ();`

will give you a very simple map with a key type of String and Value type of Object.

Edit: This is a non-thread safe version.

You can check out [ConcurrentHashMaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for a thread-safe map.