# Java store varying machine data in object

Tags: java

I need to be able to store incoming data from production machines to perform some calculations on it. I receive the data from an API and it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "datasetId":23
        "timestamp":1538125706336,
        "machineData":[
            {
                "machineId":<UUID>,
                "type":"PLASTIC_INJECTOR",
                "data":[
                    "temperature":30,
                    "pressure":32
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]

    },
    ...
]
```

The machineData array contains multiple different types of machines which emmit different measurements. Some have temperature others have for example 'consumed water volume'. Also some machines are offline due to maintenance etc. so the array does not always contain the same machines. My question is how I would store this information in an object.

My idea was this:

```
public class MachineData{
    private long datasetId,
    private long timestamp;
    private Map<UUID, MachineDataEntry> dataPerMachine;
}

public class MachineDataEntry{
    private Map<String, float> measurements;
}
```

So the MachineDataEntry represents the contents of the "data" array for each machine in "machineData".

I tested it and it works on development but I am worried that as soon as I need to process API responses with >10000 entries I might get performance issues.

Is there any more intelligent way to do this?

Comment: Do you always need all those entries in one response? A response with that many entries might cause performance issues anyways no matter how you structure those entries.

Comment: yes I need all this data and also I can not edit the api to only deliver a fraction, it is out of reach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps are really fast. Only thing is you might want to pick `HashMap` or `TreeMap`. `HashMap` is more time-efficient (O(1) operations) and `TreeMap` is more space-efficient (no rehashing, but O(log(n)) operations).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001992/quickest-implementation-of-java-map-for-a-small-number-of-entries) question is somewhat related. When you quickly add a lot of elements to `HashMap` it might need to be re-hashed a lot and that would tank the performance, but you can fix it by setting high capacity (or capacity increment) at initialization if you expect a lot of entries.

Comment: The data structure does not need to be thread-safe. Usually there are approx. 8 machines connected and each provide about 2 measurements. Is HashMap fitting for this amount of data?

Comment: Perfectly so. Only downside of HasMap is it is unsorted, meaning if you decide tobiterate over it, it will return items not in the order you put it in.